# jQuery append to nest array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Is it possible to use `push` or similar method to target a specific nest array within an a JSON object?

Below is an example of a JSON object:

```
var json = [
        { "Id": 0, "Fruits": [{ "FruitId": 0, "Amount": null }] },
        { "Id": 1, "Fruits": [{ "FruitId": 2, "Amount": { "IsNull": false, "Value": 50.0000 } }, { "FruitId": 8, "Amount": { "IsNull":
false, "Value": 700.0000 } }]}, 
        { "Id": 2, "Fruits": [{ "FruitId": 0, "Amount": null }] },
        { "Id": 3, "Fruits": [{ "FruitId": 0, "Amount": null }] }
    ];

var output = JSON.stringify(json);

var fruitsArray = $.parseJSON(output);
```

I would like to insert `{"FruitId":8,"Amount":50}` into Fruits at Id: 2

From examples I've seen re `push` it simply pushes an object to the end of the JSON object, where as I would like to be able to append dynamically.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: do you want to insert or replace?

Answer (score 0):

You first have to find index and then insert data on that index.

```
   var json = [
            { "Id": 0, "Fruits": [{ "FruitId": 0, "Amount": null }] },
            { "Id": 1, "Fruits": [{ "FruitId": 2, "Amount": { "IsNull": false, "Value": 50.0000 } }, { "FruitId": 8, "Amount": { "IsNull": false, "Value": 700.0000 } }]}, 
            { "Id": 2, "Fruits": [{ "FruitId": 0, "Amount": null }] },
            { "Id": 3, "Fruits": [{ "FruitId": 0, "Amount": null }] }
        ];


    var indexNo = json.findIndex(function(obj) {
        return obj['Id'] == 2;
    });
    indexNo != -1 ? json[indexNo]['Fruits'].push({"FruitId":8,"Amount":5000}) : "Not found";
```

--------------find index with for loop-----------

```
var json = [
            { "Id": 0, "Fruits": [{ "FruitId": 0, "Amount": null }] },
            { "Id": 1, "Fruits": [{ "FruitId": 2, "Amount": { "IsNull": false, "Value": 50.0000 } }, { "FruitId": 8, "Amount": { "IsNull": false, "Value": 700.0000 } }]}, 
            { "Id": 2, "Fruits": [{ "FruitId": 0, "Amount": null }] },
            { "Id": 3, "Fruits": [{ "FruitId": 0, "Amount": null }] }
        ];

var indexNo = -1;
   for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            if(json[i]['Id'] == 2) {
                indexNo = i;
                break;
            }
    }
    indexNo != -1 ? json[indexNo]['Fruits'].push({"FruitId":8,"Amount":5000}) : "Not found";
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am getting `0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'findIndex'` when trying to run your code.

Comment: seems your browser not support this function ... older version i think!, i have updated ans where index is find with help of for loop

Answer (score -1):

And another approach:

```
 $.each(json,function(ix,record) {
           if(record.Id == 2)
              {
                  record.Fruits.push({"FruitId":8,"Amount":50})
               }
               });
```

Comment: Thank you, that replaces the current Fruits array, not append.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the function `find` to look for the specific object and then add it to the array.

```js
let array = [{    "Id": 0,    "Fruits": [{      "FruitId": 0,      "Amount": null    }]  },  {    "Id": 1,    "Fruits": [{      "FruitId": 2,      "Amount": {        "IsNull": false,        "Value": 50.0000      }    }, {      "FruitId": 8,      "Amount": {        "IsNull": false,        "Value": 700.0000      }    }]  },  {    "Id": 2,    "Fruits": [{      "FruitId": 0,      "Amount": null    }]  },  {    "Id": 3,    "Fruits": [{      "FruitId": 0,      "Amount": null    }]  }],
    targetId = 2,
    object = {"FruitId":8,"Amount":50},
    target = array.find(({Id}) => Id === targetId);

if (target) target.Fruits = [...target.Fruits, object];

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```